# What's a word to describe black humor of the variety that criticizes the injustices of the world?

Tags: adjectives, word-formation, compound-adjectives

For example, let's say I see a homeless man and woman eating scraps of food next to a garbage fire to keep warm and I say to my friend, "Must be date night" (with undertones of "This is a sad world"). Looking for an adjective, preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ["kafkaesque"](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/12/29/nyregion/the-essence-of-kafkaesque.html)

> "You don't give up, you don't lie down and die. What you do is
>   struggle against this with all of your equipment, with whatever you
>   have. But of course you don't stand a chance. That's Kafkaesque."

Comment: @Tyler glad to be of help! :)

Comment: I would suggest use "Kafkaesque" exclusively in non-fiction writing. In fiction, mentioning "reading" or other "authors" breaks the reader's suspension of disbelief.

Answer (score 6):

**Satire** is clearly the form.  The adjective may be **sardonic**.  The overall sense is **cynical**.